# Result set with multiple rows based on max date and not NULL

Tags: aggregate, window-functions, firebird

Staff changed their profiles as shown in this table:

[image]

The result of latest information should be like this:

[image]

I applied the technique from [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17217/returning-a-result-set-with-multiple-rows-based-on-max-date) for embedded Firebird of LibreOffice Base, the query has error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT StaffCode, 
       FIRST_VALUE(FirstName) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY StaffCode 
                 ORDER BY CASE WHEN FirstName IS NOT NULL 
                               THEN EffectiveDate 
                               END DESC) FirstName, 
       FIRST_VALUE(LastName)  
           OVER (PARTITION BY StaffCode  
                 ORDER BY CASE WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL  
                               THEN EffectiveDate 
                               END DESC) LastName, 
       FIRST_VALUE(MarriageStatus)  
           OVER (PARTITION BY StaffCode  
                 ORDER BY CASE WHEN MarriageStatus IS NOT NULL  
                               THEN EffectiveDate 
                               END DESC) MarriageStatus
FROM SourceTable;
```